# SCNNode Rotation Multiple Axes

Tags: swift, rotation, scnnode

This [Question](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/6sg3dj/how_to_rotate_scnnode_around_x_and_y_axis_in_the/) was posted, but never answered.

Similar to [This Question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116676/why-is-scnnode-rotation-property-a-four-dimensional-vector), I am trying to understand `SCNNode.rotation` as a 4D vector. The prior question utilizes an example that only manipulates 1 axis, i.e.,

```
SCNNode.rotation = (0, 0, 1, degToRad(45)) //Rotate about z-axis by 45 degrees
```

which makes sense; however, what if I wanted to rotate the X axis by 20 degrees, Y axis by 45 degrees and then Z axis by 78 degrees?

```
SCNNode.rotation = ??
```

I would provide code I've tried, but I don't understand conceptually the notion of a 4D rotation vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every node just has a transform with 4x4 matrix. So all the rotation operations are reflecting in the changing the transform.

In this case, if you change either of rotation, eulerAngles and orientation, you are supposed to get same value.

If rotating about three axises, I suggested using eulerAngles.

`node.eulerAnges = SCNVector3(x:degToRad(20),y:degToRad(45), z:degToRad(78))`

After you set this, go back and check to value of rotation:

`SCNVector4(x: -0.16975601, y: 0.5943193, z: 0.786109, w: 1.448788)`

This means there is an axis going through point(-0.16975601, 0.5943193, 0.786109) and origin (0,0,0), and node is rotating around it for  1.448788 (82 degree).

Comment: Just read another post saying using `eulerAngles` is easier. Thanks for this. `eulerAngles` is just too obvious for me to come up with quickly lol.